# Marginalized non Markov Chapman kolmogorov equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

The usual Chapman kolmogorov equation states $$\int dx_1 p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1|x_0)=p(x_2|x_0)$$
Which means we can also identify
$$\int dx_0 p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1|x_0)p(x_0)=p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)$$
Now, because $$\int dx_0 p(x_2,x_1,x_0)=p(x_2,x_1)$$
We can write the non Markov case as
$$\int dx_0 p(x_3|x_2,x_1,x_0)p(x_2|x_1,x_0)p(x_1|x_0)p(x_0)=p(x_3|x_2,x_1)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)$$
The problem I have is that I have an integral in the form $$\int dx_0 p(x_3|x_2,x_1,x_0)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1|x_0)p(x_0)$$
Where $$p(x_2|x_1)=\frac{\int dx_0 p(x_2,x_1,x_0)}{\int dx_0 p(x_1,x_0)}$$
My question is can I simply marginalize over the nuisance variable as before and get 
$$\int dx_0 p(x_3|x_2,x_1,x_0)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1|x_0)p(x_0)=p(x_3|x_2,x_1)p(x_2|x_1)p(x_1)$$
And if not why not and can we write it as anything else?